# require.js (rjs) stopped working after migrationg from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

I am getting 404 error on what used to work.

```
10:35:40.588 [warn] application - [onHandlerNotFound] GET /assets/javascripts/require.js?v=807475 - 127.0.0.1
```

I checked the configuration guide for sbt-rjs plugin:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/RequireJS-support

But everything was already set up on my side - since it worked fine on 2.3

plugin.sbt:

```
// The Typesafe repository resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")

// BuildInfo available in java addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.2.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-stylus" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
```

build.sbt:

```
...
// Asset building pipeline
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs,gzip)
...
```

HTML template:
    
        require = {
            urlArgs: 'v=@Urls.ASSETS_VERSION',
            waitSeconds: 180
        };

```
<script data-main="@Urls.assetWithoutVersion("javascripts/main.js")" src="@Urls.asset("javascripts/require.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML rendered:

```
<script>
    require = {
        urlArgs: 'v=807475',
        waitSeconds: 180
    };
</script>

<script data-main="//local.prizeo.com:9000/assets/javascripts/main.js" src="//local.prizeo.com:9000/assets/javascripts/require.js?v=807475" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Anyone else experienced this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Possibly not important info, but adding it for completeness.
We use custom Urls class to be able to use cloud front:

```
public static String assetWithoutVersion(String path) {
    if (Protocols.HTTP.isUsed(path) || Protocols.HTTPS.isUsed(path)) {

        if(Protocols.HTTP.isUsed(path)) {
            //this should be avoided, since some browsers may refuse o load unsecured content
            DLogger.warn(TAG, "Asset file '" + path + "' has the protocol specified");
        }

    } else if(Protocols.NONE.isUsed(path)) {
        //this is fine
    } else {
        if (USE_CLOUDFRONT_ASSETS) {
            path = Protocols.NONE + getCloudfrontUrl() + "/assets/" + path;
        } else {
            //strip the http or https
            String domain = Play.application().configuration().getString("page.url.base");
            domain = domain.substring(domain.indexOf('/') + 2);
            path = Protocols.NONE + domain + "/assets/" + path;
        }
    }

    return path;

}

public static String asset(String path) {
    //no need to include version on s3 assets
    if (path.contains("static-assets-")) return path;

    return assetWithoutVersion(path) + "?v=" + ASSETS_VERSION;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Adding the route.conf line (note: I have not updated the router to the "injected" version). Could it be an issue?

```
GET         /assets/*file                                                              controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file: String)
```

Comment: `@Urls.assetWithoutVersion` is it custom class/method?

Comment: It's custom class, I have added implementation for completeness - it's there to handle CDN.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to change 2 things:

The rendered HTML has to be:

```
<script data-main="//local.prizeo.com:9000/assets/javascripts/main.js" src="/assets/lib/requirejs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note the "lib" prefix instead of javascripts

I also had to add:

```
RjsKeys.paths += ("jsRoutes" -> ("/jsroutes" -> "empty:"))
```

To the build.sbt

Please comment if you know what it does - I found it in sample play projects and haven't found any documentation for it.